# What is a better way of saying

Tags: phrases

What is a better way of saying 'apologies for the typo error'? Typographical also does not sound too good.

Comment: you don't have to apologise for minor typos

Comment: @JonMarkPerry You can't assume that.

Comment: I usually see the abbreviation "typo" used as a noun all by itself. I would just say "apologies for the typo" without the word "error."

Comment: _Typo_ is (informal) short for "a typographical error". "Apologies for the typo".

Answer (score 1):

***Typo*** is a type of error already. See [*typo* in Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typo)

> : an error (as of spelling) in typed or typeset material
>
> […]
>
> Origin and Etymology of TYPO
> short for *typographical (error)*

So I’d say, “Apologies for the typo,” or, especially in formal communication, “Apologies for the typographical error.”

Answer (score 0):

> **mistype** (v.)
>   1. Make a mistake in typing (a word or letter)
>
> <sup>Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mistype)</sup>

This is probably the most formal wording you'll get. However, most dictionaries list it only as a verb even though it could be used as a noun in your sentence. See [this Dictionary.com entry](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mistype) for noun form.

> Apologies for the mistype.